# Problems getting python-docx working with a Python script being executed by a Rails app hosted on Heroku

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, python-3.x, heroku, python-docx

TLDR: My python script which my rails app on heroku fires fails at "from docx import Document" due to some unicode/lxml dependency thing.

```
    2015-08-25T22:09:35.561165+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
    2015-08-25T22:09:35.561172+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "individual_insights_survey_report.py", line 4, in <module>
    2015-08-25T22:09:35.561181+00:00 app[web.1]:     from docx import Document
    2015-08-25T22:09:35.561222+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docx/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    2015-08-25T22:09:35.561254+00:00 app[web.1]:     from docx.api import Document  # noqa
    2015-08-25T22:09:35.561277+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docx/api.py", line 14, in <module>
    2015-08-25T22:09:35.561312+00:00 app[web.1]:     from docx.package import Package
    2015-08-25T22:09:35.561336+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docx/package.py", line 11, in <module>
    2015-08-25T22:09:35.561369+00:00 app[web.1]:     from docx.opc.package import OpcPackage
    2015-08-25T22:09:35.561391+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docx/opc/package.py", line 12, in <module>
    2015-08-25T22:09:35.561421+00:00 app[web.1]:     from .part import PartFactory
    2015-08-25T22:09:35.561443+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docx/opc/part.py", line 12, in <module>
    2015-08-25T22:09:35.561473+00:00 app[web.1]:     from .oxml import serialize_part_xml
    2015-08-25T22:09:35.561495+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docx/opc/oxml.py", line 12, in <module>
    2015-08-25T22:09:35.561533+00:00 app[web.1]:     from lxml import etree
    2015-08-25T22:09:35.561628+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_DecodeLatin1
```

I thought this might be a versioning thing, but can't seem to find versions that will work as it does locally. This is probably a Python + Heroku thing as this is my first time trying to any sort of Python on Heroku.

Specifically I found this [mailgroup post](https://mailman-mail5.webfaction.com/pipermail/lxml/2012-September/006572.html) which mentions:

> lxml can support either UCS4 or UCS2 as the internal Unicode
>   representation, but the switch is made at compile-time.
>
> Make sure that the Python that compiled etree.so and the Python that
>   uses it are the same. Same version (at least minor as in 2.7.x, maybe
>   micro as in 2.7.3), same architecture, and in this case same Unicode
>   settings (UCS4 vs UCS2.)
>
> The easiest way to do this is to re-install lxml from the source
>   tarball. Do you still have this issue?"

So I tried to figure out what version of Python was used (failed) and then tried specifying different versions at runtime.txt to try and make it work.

> **Caveat:** here's a lot of pieces in the chain and I'm not very familiar with most of them -- so if I need to provide more information to give context -- please let me know!

**Full Context:** My company has a Ruby on Rails Webapp that's basically a self service platform for generating data reports for our Client Delivery team.

The Rails App, via a click of a button, should fire a Python script which opens up an Excel Spreadsheet (openpyxl) and does runs some data analysis on it and then outputs a report in a Microsoft Word (python-docx) document that is downloaded in a zip file.

This is definitely a suboptimal/overly complicated way to do this, but I inherited the Webapp and am just trying to work within its structure for now.

I have the Python script working fine when run locally and stand alone (no rails/ruby/heroku) with:

```
Python ver: 2.7.5
openpyxl==2.2.5
python-docx==0.8.5
```

I've tried the heroku app with:
Python versions: 2.7.3, 2.7.5, 2.7.9, 2.7.10 with the error above.
This is with requirements.txt looking like:

```
python-docx==0.8.5
openpyxl==2.2.5
lxml==3.4.4
```

Added lxml to be safe.

When I use Python versions: 3.2.5, 3.3.3

Where I get this error:

```
    2015-08-25T23:38:59.793177+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named site
```

Any help on how to resolve this would be great! Do I need to re-install Python or a module? Is that even doable on Heroku? Am I missing a dependency? A configuration thing? Help :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was my own stupidity -- basically I was using "python " to fire the python script which generated the unhelpful "ImportError: No module named site" instead of "python3 "

Switched and things were fine! So if you get that error, that might be what's happening ;p